# Laravel 5.1 ManyToMany tags on blogs not working

Tags: php, orm, tags, many-to-many, laravel-5.1

I have a very, very strange problem.

What I try to do is to create tags on my blog posts. Therefor I use a ManyToMany relationship.

This is a fresh installed Laravel 5.1:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'BlogController@show');
```

**Models**

**Blog.php**

```
class Blog extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');
    }
}
```

**Tag.php**

```
class Tag extends Model
{

    public function blogs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Blog');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

**BlogController.php**

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{

    public function show($id)
    {
        $blog = Blog::find($id);
        return view('welcome', compact('blog'));
    }
}
```

**Welcome.blade.php**

```
<h1>{{ $blog->title }}</h1>

<h2>Tags</h2>

@foreach($blog->tags as $tag)
    <p>{{$tag->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

All the required tables are created (blogs, tags, blog_tag) and some posts and tags are created and relations are set (attach) in blog_tag.

**When I run this I get this error**

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /var/www/vue.nl/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

It seems that is has something to do with $blog->tags. If I change it to **$blog->tagss** and also change the method name in **Blog.php** to tagss ( **public function tagss()** ) it is working flawlessly...

I don't get it. I know I can simply change it to tagss or something else but I am following simple tutorials here, so this should work?

Is 'tags' a reserved word or is there something else I don't see? Again, this is a fresh Laravel Installation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the `$blog` variable directly to the `view()` function

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{

    public function show($id)
    {
        $blog = Blog::find($id);
        return view('welcome', ['blog' => $blog]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: blog (View: /var/www/vue.nl/resources/views/welcome.blade.php). Seems not logical either considering that changing the method name works.

Comment: Ah my fault: replace `$blog` with `['blog' => $blog]` in the `view()` function

Comment: I already did that ;-) Still the same original issue: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /var/www/vue.nl/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Comment: Ok lets analyze the variable. Would you tell me the var_dump of $blog in your view. `{{ var_dump($blog) }}` and `{{ var_dump($blog->tags) }}` would be useful.

Comment: Damn. I was tidying up the blog table so the dump has only relevant fields and discovered a field named 'tags'... Took me hours to discover this. Removed it and the problem is solved. So stupid!